# Trying to use axios to make API call in a React/Phoenix App (using Brunch)

Tags: node.js, npm, phoenix-framework, brunch, axios

I'm trying to make use of the [axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios) library to call some API endpoints.

My project setup is a Phoenix app (with brunch for asset management) and a React app (all in the `web/static/js` directory)

Most npm modules are ok, I do:

`npm install --save _module-name_`

Then I add the module to the `brunch-config.js` into the `npm whitelist` array.

Which I've done with axios, so it doesn't complain that it cannot find the library.

However, when I try and use axios e.g `axios.post`

I get the following error in the JS Console:

`Cannot find module "axios/lib/adapters/xhr"`

It's like brunch isn't loading in the axios dependencies (even though I can see that file if i navigate to `node_modules/axios/lib/adapters`

Has anyone had this issue (with any npm module and brunch/phoenix) and if so how do you go about fixing it?

**Update**

It seems to be a wider spread problem with brunch.

I also cannot use "React-Bootstrap" I get a similar error where it cannot find the sub-dependencies....

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and updated brunch to the latest (2.7.5 at the time), which resolved my issue.

See https://github.com/brunch/brunch/issues/1136